# fold/unfold selection only in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, folding

Notepad++ has commands to fold/unfold all the document. Is that possible to select some of the lines and fold/unfold only the blocks lying inside the selection?

## EDIT1

Any notepad++ plugin which enables this capability?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry but Notepad++ don't haves that option.

It has a similar option called "Hide lines"

1. Select the text you want to hide
2. Right button click
3. Select `Hide Lines`.

Instead of a <kbd>+</kbd> symbol you will see two blue arrows showing there are some lines hidden.

Comment: Well, I want the lines inside the blocks to be invisible, but I need the first and last lines of each block to be visible, so I know there is a block there. I just don't want the details to clutter the view.

Comment: I know what you need, but Notepad++ don't has that option. Just don't select first and last line of the block you want to hide using my answer ;-)

Comment: I would have to do it to each block, so it will be the same as folding one by one

Answer (score 4):

Notepad++ folding mechanism detects parts of the documents that are enclosed in braces `{}`. Whatever lines are enclosed in braces can be folded and unfolded using the '+' and '-' handles on the left, next to line numbers. 
You can have nested folds as well!

Comment: No, I do not want to click every +/- symbol, I want to select some lines and do the folding/unfolding of those parts automatically.

Comment: how about `view > Fold all (alt-0)` or `view > Unfold all (alt-shift-0)` to fold or unfold all in selection? Also for more control can also use `View > Collapse Current Level` or `View > Uncollapse Current Level`

Comment: fold/unfold all works on the whole document regardless of selection

Comment: Old post, but @JoshuaKlein was on the right track. Click inside the node you want to collapse and then choose View > Collapse Current Level. That's not the selected area, but it's a heck of a lot closer than clicking every single '-' icon.

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl-clicking a fold point (+/-) will recursively unfold/fold all blocks inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Change the Language to C# or Java or JavaScript to enable collapsing comments and brackets.

1. Menu option:
   Language - C - C# (or use shortcut - Alt, L, C, C, Enter)
2. Then try these out:

   ```
    /*hello
    hello
    */

    {hello
    hello
    }
   ```

Comment: This doesn't make sense, reread the question.

Comment: Ah I understand.

Comment: The closest I have gotten is to highlight a section of collapsed content and modifying such as on the right click menu selecting "UPPERCASE" and then Undo, i'm not sure if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that, if your code blocks are folded and you hit Enter and then select Undo, NPP will unfold only the code block where the cursor is. I use this trick in macros.

Answer (score 0):

Save the file as a .cs and use {} as the beginning and ending of each section you wish to collapse.